# Automatic continuity in Banach algebras

Tags: banach-algebras

I have the following two questions

> **1:** Let $A$ and $B$ be Banach algebras and suppose that $B$ is semisimple. Let $T:A \to B  $  be a homomorphism with $\overline {TA}=B.$ Is $T$ automatically continuous?
>
> **2:** Let $A$ and $B$ be Banach algebras. Let $T:A \to B  $  be a homomorphism with $\overline {TA}=B.$ Is $T$ automatically continuous?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify: is Q2 merely Q1 without the assumption that $B$ is semisimple?

Comment: Have you had a look in H. Garth Dales' "Banach Algebras and Automatic Continuity"?  This seems to be *the* reference for such questions.

Comment: @Dear yemon Choi, yes in 2 we consider B without semisimple

Comment: @JochenGlueck In fairness to the OP he or she may be relying on GoogleBooks if his or her library does not have a copy of the book, and it is not one where everyone has the immediate resources to own a physical copy. ("Far too expensive" -- H. G. Dales, personal communication over coffee)

Comment: To the OP: that said, if you do have access to a physical or PDF copy, please look there first